# How Regex backreference work

Tags: java, regex

i am aware of the fact that backreference ovverride values if the backtraking occurs and the ovverided output will be the new backreference.

but if i take this regex for example:

```
([abc]+).*\1
```

then for the string:`"abc me bca"`

the output is:`"abc me bca"`

can someone explain how is that possible because as per the steps:

```
-[abc] matches a from the input.

-because their is an quantifier + so it will repeate one or more 
time and again matches b and c.then stops at whitespace as it's 
not either 'a', 'b' or 'c'.

-.* eats all the input string after abc and further goes 
to \1(the backreference).

- .* will do backtracking as \1 fails and because .* i.e zero 
or more so it will through all the charecters and again the + 
of [abc]+ will do backtracking.

-in backtracking of [abc]+ it will be do until 'a' after 
removing 'b' and 'c' but still their is no match for 
\1 as bca.
```

so how the output came as "abc me bca"..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First character is `a` and last character is `a`.So its a match.

What happens is `abc` is captured in group then compared with `bca`.it fails.

So engine backtracks by 1.Now `ab` will be compared to `ca`.It fails.So engine

will backtrack again.`a` is compared to last `a` and it passes.So finally engine

stores `a` in group as it satisfies the match criteria .Note `\1` is what gets

stored in the first group.It is not a fixed value.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/72

Comment: can you you please explain the ([bca]+)\s*\w*\s*\1 regex
for "abc me bca" giving "bc me bc" output.?how it is removing the first 'a'.?

Comment: @Deepak if `a` matches then `\s*\w*\s*` will not match.So engine matched `bc` .Now `\s*\w*\s*` will match with ` me `

Comment: after  [bca]+ will match "abc", can't \s*\w*\s* can match " me "..and will fail for "bca" bcoz \1 has "abc"..?

Comment: @Deepak yes it will fail ,then engine will try the next possible combination.Whenever you say `a*` it can `a,aa,aaa` .So It will try possible combinations to get match by capturing maxinum using `+` then leaving 1 by 1